# Parsing json string with python 3 from geocode

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a json string from the following url:

url = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new+york&sensor=false

using the following code

js = json.loads(url)

When I view the webpage and even the source it appears just fine. It starts with **{** and ends with **}**, which is just what python3 needs. But when I retrieve it live from the url using python3 urllib function and output the retrieved string, I discover that the format is broken. This time the string start like this

**('b\'{...**

and ends like this

**...}\n\'')**.

Below is a screenshot that captures exactly the problem I'm facing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oGNr.jpg)

Please how do I get a correctly formatted python dictionary from this url?

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

response = urlopen('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new+york&sensor=false')
data = str(response.read(), encoding='utf-8')

print(data)

my_dict = json.loads(data)

print(my_dict)
print(my_dict['status'])
```

Comment: Thanks man. So it all has to do with the encoding. I was just experimenting with geocode json data